# Illustrator CC: stroke issue with circular path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, shapes, stroke, laser

My goal is to create a circle with a .001 stroke in RGB red for laser cutting. For some reason I cannot create ANY .001 paths without a strange variable stroke and I cannot figure out why. With this path, my laser won't read it as vector and I can't cut the shape I want.

Why is my stroke all over the place?

[image: shows screenshot of variable width stroke of a circle]

Comment: it's only happening for circle. if you draw straight line then no problems so basically to solve this issue how about using stroke equivalent to 0.0019 or 0.002 :D

Comment: How do you know it's not just a rendering bug? have you tried exporting this to a PDF or actually using the laser cut?

Comment: Try **View- > Previwe on CPU**

Answer (score 0):

Must be something wrong with your AI settings or maybe there's some effect applied to the stroke. I tried this in my AI CS6 because it sounded strange and don't seem to replicate the issue, here's a 0.001pt stroked circle below. Try [restoring](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/setting-preferences.html) your AI preferences.

[image]

Comment: AI source file at https://we.tl/t-2fPzag6wnD

Comment: i have distortion on top right corner of your ai file. maybe preferences issues !

Comment: Could be a CC bug —  I am using CS6. If you do a Save for Web, is that actually saved into an export? Maybe its just a preview thing, video card issue?

Comment: I can see the glitch with AI CC 2018 in the file shared by @Lucian , and it looks some kind of rendering bug. If you switch off GPU graphics in the preferences, it disappears.